# OpenLayers 3 Defining axis ordering

Tags: geometry, coordinates, openlayers, openlayers-3

I run into a problem that my GeoJSON return coordinates in a latitude/longitude order, but OpenLayers wants them to be in reversed order: longitude/latitude.
And I cant't get them another way from server.
Is it possible to reverse coordinates using OL3, like I found something about old OL like this

```
 formatOptions: { xy: false }
```

Does something like this available in OL3?

Comment: GeoJSON is strictly in CRS:84 projection only, which is lon/lat order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. OL3 only accepts XY. If you have the possibility to reverse it in your GeoJSON source, do that.

In the ol3 documentation you should have the possiblity to make a custom transform by using the method "applyTransform" on each of your geometries in your featrures, but but this method is appearently removed.

Below is a suggestion to how you can reverse your coordinates.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.myjsonsource.com",
        timeout: 1000,
        success: function(response) {
            var layerJSONString = $.parseJSON(response);
            var size=layerJSONString.features.length;
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
                layerJSONString.features[i].geometry.coordinates.reverse();
            };
            vectorSource.addFeatures(vectorSource.readFeatures(response));

        },
        error: loadError        
});
```

Comment: For me it did not swap coordinates in vectorSource, so I reversed them in response and only after that added features to the vectorSource

Comment: @Anuket, if you have edit privileges, could you change the code above to the code that works for you and accept the answer. It will do it more usefull for others who will come in the same situation.